# IPad not scrollable on page with javascript UI Draggable page

Tags: javascript, iscroll4

Ok so I have a site that uses the javascript UI draggable mouse option for the web page but then when someone accesses the page from either their iphone or ipad the UI draggable script doesnt work? Is there any easy fixes for it? I was trying to find something like the iscroll for it but was unsure if I am going in the right direction.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer through this page 
https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch